# Why is using decorator factory factory functions a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-decorators

Say I have a decorator factory factory. It is quite useless, just accumulating the arguments, and adding to the results, but just for an example:

```
def decorator_factory_factory(a):
    def decorator_factory(b):
        def decorator(f):
            def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
                return f(*args, **kwargs) + a + b
            return decorated
        return decorator
    return decorator_factory
```

And I try to use it like this:

```
@decorator_factory_factory(3)(1)
def should_return_5():
    return 1
```

I get a SyntaxError. Surely it should allow any arbitrary Python expression as a decorator?

I also tried:

```
@(decorator_factory_factory(3)(1))
def should_not_be_touched():
    return 1
```

but this was another SyntaxError.

Am I doing something wrong? The only way I have found around this is:

```
_decorator_factory = decorator_factory_factory(3)
@_decorator_factory(1)
def should_not_be_touched():
    return 1
del _decorator_factory
```

But this requires an additional variable that needs to be deleted

Comment: What version of Python are you using, @Artyer?

Comment: @ChristianDean Happens on 3.6.1 and 2.7.13 on Windows, and the default python2 and 3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Ayter Interesting. I asked because because apparently the author of [this](http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2010/09/decorator-factories-and-decorator.html) article could use the decorator factory factory syntax. I thought he might have been using Python 2.7 where the syntax worked, but it failed on that version to. I'm going to check using Python v2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** This is no longer a syntax error as of Python 3.9. See [PEP 614](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0614/).

---

The decorator syntax [is restricted](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax). You're not allowed arbitrary expressions. You are allowed to use the `.` operator and at most a single call `()` at the end, so

```
@decorator_factory_factory(3)(1)
def should_return_5():
    return 1
```

is a syntax error since it has a call `(3)` that is not at the end.

In practice, this is not that limiting, because decorators are just sugar for an assignment after the function declaration. You can do this yourself without the restriction,

```
def should_return_5():
    return 1
should_return_5 = decorator_factory_factory(3)(1)(should_return_5)
```

which does not create an additional variable that needs to be deleted.

Furthermore, the single function call is sufficient to sneak in arbitrary expressions via a simple identity function.

```
def identity(x):
    return x

@identity(decorator_factory_factory(3)(1))
def should_return_5():
    return 1
```

With a shorter name for `identity` (not `id`, that's a builtin), this gets pretty close to the `@(decorator_factory_factory(3)(1))` syntax that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

the function was send on wrong wrapper and never called

```
def decorator_factory_factory(): 
    def decorator_factory(f):
        def decorator():
            return f()
        return decorator
    return decorator_factory

@decorator_factory_factory()
def should_not_be_touched():
    return 1
```

Comment: A decorator factory shouldn't take the function. The decorator should take the function. The example just returned the function unchanged. I hope the example is more clear now for what I would want to do. `decorator_factory_factory` is now just a decorator factory.